# How can I prove to users of the software that the binaries I post match source code that's been inspected and verified by a third party?

Tags: source-code, opensource

If I have software that's like TrueCrypt where security is very important, but unlike TrueCrypt because mine won't [mysteriously go offline for seemingly no reason at all](http://truecrypt.sourceforge.net/), how can I prove that my binaries that I post on the site match the source code that has been independently verified?

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23017607/does-building-two-exact-matching-c-sharp-projects-on-different-computers-always), it seems independently building from the source code doesn't generate the same executable every time.

I want to be able to prove there are no backdoors, because this, unlike TrueCrypt, will involve remote data storage, and I don't want anyone to think keys could be leaked in any possible way at all.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot prove that the binary you provide really matches a given source code. It is not *theoretically* impossible but it would require substantial cooperation on the part of the compiler. Some researchers are working on that subject for some languages which are better suited to that task than C (mostly ML or Lisp derivative). In any case, there is no readily available product yet, and won't be for some time, so in practice, that's not an option.

Your best options are then:

- Provide the source code (with proof that it is the same archive as the one used by the independent reviewer) so that the users may do the compilation themselves.
- Ask the people who ran the "independent review" to actually do the compilation and provide the resulting binary.

In any case, users will have to trust *someone*: you, the independent reviewers... in as much the same way as they have to trust Microsoft, Intel, AMD and all other parties involved in the building of the computer. So maybe the question is not the right one. The *compiler itself* may push a backdoor on clean source code (there is a [very classic example](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=358210) of that kind of trick). Instead of asking how you could prove that the compilation step did not include a backdoor, you should ask: how may I build enough of a good reputation so that people will trust me ?

Comment: Yeah maybe the reviewer compile it, send you the resulting binaries, you host those yourself alongside a link to the reviewer's checksum page. (if that is a thing)

Comment: The comments on trusting someone are spot on, though the answer does overlook [deterministic builds, as Terry Chia explains in this answer](http://security.stackexchange.com/a/57264/39623).  Compiler bugs and